# How to update the following multiple columns scenario using Case?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen case being used for updating one column when conditions are different. My requirement is I have to update 2 columns based on same condition.

Conditions are same for both columns but I want to avoid repetitive query condition.

```
update t1  set  col1= case when col3='A' and col4='AA' then 'A1' else 'B1' end
               ,col2= case when col3='A' and col4='AA' then 'A2' else 'B2' end
```

In the above query the conditions for update of the col1 and col2 is same but I have to write it fully write case statement for both columns.

Is there any way to combine the case conditions only one time for two columns?

Comment: Your `case` _expressions_ have no terminating `end`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `case` is long and complicated you could do something like this `merge`, shorten it in *source* part to a single value:

```
merge into t1 t
using (select rowid rwd, case when (col3, col4) in (('A', 'AA')) then 1 else 0 end val from t1) s
on (t.rowid = s.rwd)
when matched then update set
  col1 = case val when 1 then 'A1' else 'B1' end,
  col2 = case val when 1 then 'A2' else 'B2' end
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a4265a60d288b1b6d52c41de44511f9a)</sup>**